# Sharing layers across files in gimp

Tags: plugins, photoshop, gimp

So photoshop has this awesome feature in which you can use layers from a template .psd file and updating those layers in the template, automatically updates the other files using them.

Is there something like this on gimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know. If that's true for PS, this seems quite dangerous...